# Spring AMQP RabbitMQ implementing priority queue

Tags: java, apache-camel, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

After Google for a few days, and i believe i am totally lost.  I would like to implement a kind of priority queue that has about 3 queues:

1. high priority queue (daily), that needs to be process first.
2. mid priority queue (weekly), that will process if no items in queue #1. (it is ok message in this queue it never process at all)
3. low priority queue (monthly), that will process if no items in queue #1 & #2. (it is ok message in this queue it never process at all)

Initially I have the following flow, to have a consumer to consume messages from all three queues and checks whether there is any items in queue #1, #2 and #3. and then I realize that this is wrong because:

1. I am totally lost with a question: "How do I know which queue it is coming from?".
2. I'm already consuming a message regardless from any queue, So if I get an object from lower priority queue, am I gonna put it back to the queue if I discover there is a message at the higher priority queue?

Following is my current configurations, which shows what an idiot I am.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd">

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" />

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplatead_daily" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    exchange="" routing-key="daily_queue"/>

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplatead_weekly" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    exchange="" routing-key="weekly_queue"/>

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplatead_monthly" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    exchange="" routing-key="monthly_queue"/>

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener ref="Consumer" method="consume" queue-names="daily_queue" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener ref="Consumer" method="consume" queue-names="weekly_queue" />
</rabbit:listener-container>    

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener ref="Consumer" method="consume" queue-names="monthly_queue" />
</rabbit:listener-container>    

<bean id="Consumer" class="com.test.Consumer" />

</beans>
```

Any idea how should I tackle this with priority queue?

ps: I also wonder, if Apache Camel has something I can depend on?

UPDATE 1: I just saw this from Apache Camel: "https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-2537"   the sequencer on JMSPriority seems to be what im looking for, anyone has tried this before?

UPDATE 2: assuming i am to use RabbitMQ's plugin base on @Gary Russell recommendation, I have the following spring-rabbitmq context XML configuration, which seems to make sense (by guest..):

```
<rabbit:queue name="ad_google_dfa_reporting_queue">
    <rabbit:queue-arguments>
            <entry key="x-max-priority" value="10"/>
    </rabbit:queue-arguments>
</rabbit:queue>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener ref="adGoogleDfaReporting" method="consume" queue-names="ad_google_dfa_reporting_queue" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id="Consumer" class="com.test.Consumer" />
```

The above xml configuration has successfully create a Queue, with name: "ad_google_dfa_reporting_queue", and with Parameter arguments:  x-max-priority: 10 & durable: true

But not when comes to the code that send the message with *priority*, I totally lost it. How to define the priority as mention in the Sample URL: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-priority-queue/blob/master/examples/java/src/com/rabbitmq/examples/PriorityQueue.java

```
AmqpTemplate amqpTemplateGoogleDfaReporting = (AmqpTemplate) applicationContext.getBean("amqpTemplateadGoogleDfaReporting");
amqpTemplateGoogleDfaReporting.convertAndSend("message"); // how to define message priority?
```

UPDATE 3: Based on the @Gary's answer, i manage to sent message with priority set in the message, as per image below:
[image: message priority screenshot]
 However, when i sent in 1000 messages with random priority between 1-10, the consumer is consuming message with all kinds of priority. (I was expecting only the high priority message to be consume first). following is the code for Message producer:

```
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i< 1000; i++){
        final int priority = random.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1) + 1;

        DfaReportingModel model = new DfaReportingModel();
        model.setReportType(DfaReportingModel.ReportType.FACT);
        model.setUserProfileId(0l + priority);
        amqpTemplateGoogleDfaReporting.convertAndSend(model, new MessagePostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
                message.getMessageProperties().setPriority(priority);
                return message;
            }
        });
    }
```

And following is the code for Message consumer:

```
    public void consume(DfaReportingModel message) {
        System.out.println(message.getUserProfileId());

        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
```

The result im getting:

```
9, 10, 7, 9, 6, 4, 10, 10, 3, 10, 6, 1, 5, 6, 6, 3, 4, 7, 6, 8, 3, 1, 4, 5, 5, 3, 10, 9, 5, 1, 8, 9, 6, 9, 3, 10, 7, 4, 8, 7, 3, 4, 8, 2, 6, 9, 6, 4, 7, 7, 2, 8, 4, 4, 1,
```

UPDATE 4: Problem solved! Knowing the sample code from https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-priority-queue is working in my environment, I presume that the problem is around the spring context. Hence, after countless time on try and error with different type of configurations, and I pin point the exact combination that will make this works! and is as per following:

```
    <rabbit:queue name="ad_google_dfa_reporting_queue">
    <rabbit:queue-arguments>
        <entry key="x-max-priority">
            <value type="java.lang.Integer">10</value> <!-- MUST specifically define java.lang.Integer to get it to work -->
        </entry>
    </rabbit:queue-arguments>
</rabbit:queue>
```

Without specifically define the value is Integer type, the priority queue does not work.  Finally, it is solved. Yay!

Comment: For the p.s. I suggest to add a Apache Camel tag

Comment: @mjn done. apache-camel added.

Comment: @ben75 thank you!! i was wonder how to itemize the facts :)

Comment: WOW your post was very helpful and saved me A LOT of time! thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RabbitMQ now has a [priority queue plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-priority-queue) where messages are delivered in priority order. It would be better to use that rather than your scheme of requeueing low priority messages which will be quite expensive at runtime.

**EDIT:**

When using the `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(...)` methods, and you want to set the priority property on the message, you either need to implement a custom `MessagePropertiesConverter` in the template (subclass the `DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter`) or use the `convertAnSend` variants that take a message post-processor; e.g.:

```
template.convertAndSend("exchange", "routingKey", "message", new MessagePostProcessor() {

    @Override
    public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
        message.getMessageProperties().setPriority(5);
        return message;
    }
});
```

Comment: I saw this plugin and was confused on how to implement the plugin with the Spring-rabbitmq.  Is there any xml context example that utilizing this plugin?

Comment: Russel i manage to "guess" the most likely xml context configuration, but when comes to java code that does the template.convertandsend();    the document does not have any reference on how to send in the priority.  clue?

Comment: Able to sent in messages with Priority! But strangely, the consumer  is consuming messages with all sorts of priority. Its like the priority was never being enforce. 
I have double check the rabbitMQ plugin Status, and priority queue shows as enabled:
[E] rabbitmq_priority_queue           3.3.x-72d20292

Comment: @Gray I am trying to use RabbitMQ on my localhost, but having hard time with it, can you give me any pointers regarding that

Comment: Please don't pile onto an existing question/answer - open a new question; tag it with `spring-amqp` and I'll get an email. Please provide __much more information__ than 'having hard time'.

Answer (score 3):

RabbitMQ has [priority queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html) implementation in the core as of version 3.5.0.

You can declare priority queues using the `x-max-priority` argument. This argument should be an integer indicating the maximum priority the queue should support. For example, using the Java client:

```
Channel ch = ...;
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-max-priority", 10);
ch.queueDeclare("my-priority-queue", true, false, false, args);
```

You can then publish prioritised messages using the priority field of `basic.properties`. Larger numbers indicate higher priority.

Comment: But it does not work with Quorum queues.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html